# Incrementally adding to a (2,n) array in a for loop in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to incrementally add to an array of shape (2,N) in a for loop with arrays of size (2,1) at each step of the loop. This is how I'm doing it right now:

```
x = []
a = np.array([[0.5], [0.5]])
for i in range(0, N):
    x = np.append(x, a + (np.random.randn(2, 1)/np.sqrt(5))).reshape(i+1, 2)
x = x.T
```

Is there a better way to do it without reshaping at each iteration and transposing the whole array in the end?

Comment: Is it alright for you to define the final array before the loop?

Comment: `np.column_stack([np.random.randn(2, 1)/np.sqrt(5) for i in range(0, N)])` this works?

Comment: @Chiel yes I can do it

Comment: @Zero Hmmm ... that looks good. Shouldn't it be row_stack?

Comment: Or simply : `np.random.rand(2,N)/np.sqrt(5)`.

Comment: @AmirHosseinF Does Divakar's answer not work for you?

Answer (score 1):

You can try by initializing the array at the beginning:
`x = np.zeros((2,N))` and then in the for loop fill it in with the `np.random.randn(2) / np.sqrt(5)`.

Comment: Yes, but how I do I fill it in?

Comment: See COLDSPEES' s  answer: `x[:,i] = np.random.rand(2) / np.sqrt(5)`

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have an urgent need for filling the array incrementally, you could you NumPy's random module for creating it at once:

```
x = np.random.randn(2, N) / np.sqrt(5) + 0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

`np.append` is not a good function.  Better to use `concatenate` or one of the `stacks`.  Better yet, do a list append, with a concatenate at the end.  And collect (1,2) arrays:

```
In [400]: a = np.array([[0.5], [0.5]]).T
In [401]: x = []
In [402]: for i in range(0,6):
     ...:     x.append(a+np.random.randn(1,2)/np.sqrt(5))
     ...:        
In [403]: x
Out[403]: 
[array([[ 0.53535176,  0.43666667]]),
 array([[ 0.25599309,  1.48571245]]),
 array([[ 0.82575401,  0.90599888]]),
 array([[ 0.38033551,  0.54522437]]),
 array([[ 0.41806277,  0.86227303]]),
 array([[ 0.25251664,  0.36236433]])]
In [404]: X=np.concatenate(x, axis=0)
In [405]: X
Out[405]: 
array([[ 0.53535176,  0.43666667],
       [ 0.25599309,  1.48571245],
       [ 0.82575401,  0.90599888],
       [ 0.38033551,  0.54522437],
       [ 0.41806277,  0.86227303],
       [ 0.25251664,  0.36236433]])
```

The loop can also be written as a list comprehension (as suggested in a comment).

If you created (2,) elements rather than (1,2) you could use `np.array(x)` to assemble the 2d array.

```
In [406]: a = np.array([0.5,0.5])
In [407]: x = [a+np.random.randn(2)/np.sqrt(5) for _ in range(6)]
In [408]: x
Out[408]: 
[array([ 0.26945613,  0.90210773]),
 ....
 array([ 0.76008067,  0.83912968])]
In [409]: np.array(x)
Out[409]: 
array([[ 0.26945613,  0.90210773],
       [ 0.96109886, -0.69105254],
       [-0.01010202,  0.92225443],
       [ 1.01784239,  0.21049822],
       [ 0.47476442,  0.08274172],
       [ 0.76008067,  0.83912968]])
```

`np.append` is supposed to look like a list append, but does a poor job of it.  It's better to understand right from the start how a list of arrays can be joined with `concatenate`.